# Homework Probability: Convergence of a sequence of random variables

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

I have exam tomorrow will you help me to solve this  problem

1. Given $Y_n$ are random variables with characteristic function $T_n$, show they are weakly converging to zero iff there is a $\delta>0$ so that $T_n(t)\to1$ for $|t|<\delta$.

Comment: It's not clear what's to be shown; you'll need to write it slightly more carefully.

Comment: show that if Yn are random variable with characteristic funtion Tn  which weakly convering to zero iff there is a delta>zero so that Tn(t)-->1 for mod t<delta.

Comment: Is there supposed to be another question after that? Because you labelled the question with "1" and I didn't want to change that. However, if there is no other question, it looks a bit silly.

Comment: This is a consequence of the continuity theorem for characteristic functions, so I assume you may not use that in your proof.  What can you use?

Answer (score 2):

To prepare yourself for the proof, you should sketch the function $\psi(z)= 1-\sin(z)/z$.
This is a non-negative, bounded, continuous function and $\psi(z)=0$ only at $z=0$.
Most importantly, $\psi$ is bounded away from zero outside any neighborhood of the origin. 
Intuitively, if the average $\mathbb{E}(\psi(Y))$ is small then $Y$ must be concentrated near zero.

More rigorously, we first note that 
the definition of characteristic function and Fubini's theorem give us
$$ {1\over 2\delta}\int_{-\delta}^\delta (1-T_n(t))\, dt = \mathbb{E}(\psi(\delta Y_n)).$$

Let $\delta>0$ be as in the problem statement, and fix $\varepsilon>0$.
Then $c=\inf(\psi(\delta y): |y|>\varepsilon)$ is strictly positive and 
$$ {1\over 2\delta}\int_{-\delta}^\delta (1-T_n(t))\, dt \geq c\, \mathbb{P}(|\delta Y_n|>\varepsilon).$$
The left hand side goes to zero as $n\to\infty$, and thus so does the right hand side.

This shows that $\delta Y_n\to 0$ in probability as $n\to\infty$, and hence also $Y_n$.